# Check if string has period (decimal) w/ jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to check if the provided input by the user has a decimal, then say, "Cannot convert decimals."

```
if(fldVal.match(/^.+$/g)){
    $("#fld").attr("placeholder", "Cannot convert decimals.").val("");
    // $("#fld").css("border-color", "#df4747");
    $("#fld").toggleClass("error-animation");
    $("#fld").addClass("error-color");
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

It displays the error, but it says every input is a decimal.  It displays the code even though the input is not a decimal (e.g., 75).

Here is the jsFiddle :: http://jsfiddle.net/mVWvN/

Comment: Check this http://jsfiddle.net/mVWvN/1/

Answer (score 4):

Use `indexOf` instead of regEx, like this :

```
 if (fldVal.indexOf('.')!=-1)
```

[Working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mVWvN/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 if (fldVal.match(/\./g)) {
    $("#fld").attr("placeholder", "Cannot convert decimals.").val("");
    // $("#fld").css("border-color", "#df4747");
    $("#fld").toggleClass("error-animation");
    $("#fld").addClass("error-color");
    e.preventDefault();
```

[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mVWvN/3/)

Or try this:

```
if (fldVal.indexOf('.') > -1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to find existence of one `.`. the `isNaN()` already handles the rest. So you can use `indexOf()`

Check this **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mVWvN/1/)**

Use

```
if (fldVal.indexOf('.') > -1) {..}
```

or **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mVWvN/1/)**

```
if (fldVal.match(/\./g)) {..}
```

Comment: Thanks man!  Works perfectly.  I used the .match(); approach because it will match all of the periods with "/g".